# Значение переменной видит с кавычками, как убрать?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Данный код работает:

```
declare
--sql_stmt clob;
p_file_name varchar2(100);
TYPE c_crn IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
l_crn_tab c_crn;
begin
p_file_name:='DCO_CRN_TEST.xlsx';
--sql_stmt:='select STRING_VAL bulk collect into l_crn_tab from TABLE( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.READ( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.file2blob(''EXRATE'','''||p_file_name||''') ) )';
select STRING_VAL bulk collect into l_crn_tab from TABLE( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.READ( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.file2blob('EXRATE',p_file_name) ) );
 --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
  end;
```

А если его выполнять динамически, то не работает:

```
declare
sql_stmt clob;
p_file_name varchar2(100);
TYPE c_crn IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
l_crn_tab c_crn;
begin
p_file_name:='DCO_CRN_TEST.xlsx';
sql_stmt:='select STRING_VAL bulk collect into l_crn_tab from TABLE( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.READ( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.file2blob(''EXRATE'','||p_file_name||')))';
--select STRING_VAL bulk collect into l_crn_tab from TABLE( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.READ( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.file2blob('EXRATE',p_file_name) ) );
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
  end;
```

> ОШИБКА :   Error report -
> ORA-00904: "DCO_CRN_TEST"."XLSX": недопустимый идентификатор
> ORA-06512: на  line 10
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Как сделать, чтобы оператор `lob.open` увидел название файла  `DCO_CRN_TEST.XLSX`?

```
sql_stmt:=q'[select STRING_VAL bulk collect into l_crn_tab from TABLE( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.READ( TABLEAU.as_read_xlsx.file2blob('EXRATE','||p_file_name||')))]';
```

> ORA-03001: средство не реализовано
> ORA-06512: на  line 10
> 03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
> *Cause:    This feature is not implemented.

Где ORA-06512 на этой строке:

```
dbms_lob.open( file_lob, dbms_lob.file_readonly );
```

Comment: Посяните пожайлуста, что непонятно из вопроса? Мало представить вариацию рабочего и не рабочего кода, нужно ещё знать в чём проблема ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В динамическом запросе заначения надо передовать используя `USING` переменными связывания . А чтобы получить результат запроса, надо `bulk collect into` вынести из самого текста запроса, так как это выражение не действительно в SQL.

Посмотрите, что надо изменить на таком воспроизводимом примере:

```
var rc refcursor
create or replace function readfile (
    filename varchar2) return sys.odciVarchar2List pipelined is
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop pipe row ('line'||i);
    end loop;
    return;
end;
/
declare
    filename varchar2(100) :='DCO_CRN_TEST.xlsx';
    result sys.odciVarchar2List;
    sqlstmt clob := q'[
        select column_value 
        from table (readfile (:fn))]';
begin
    execute immediate sqlstmt bulk collect into result
        using filename;
    open :rc for select column_value line from table (result);    
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
LINE
--------
line1
line2
line3
```